# How should I organize my study files for use with Intellij-IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been studying Java for a few months and I want to start using Intellij IDEA.
 For each book or source of information I have created a subdirectory and then another subdirectory for each chapter.  So my current structure is something like this:

```
/java/headfirst/chapter1
/java/headfirst/chapter2
..
/java/tutorialspoint/
/java/youtube/newboston/
/java/deitelHTP/chapter1/
/java/deitelHTP/chapter2/
..
```

That works very well when using vim and the command line.

Now with Intellij I'm looking for feedback on how best to organize my files.  It seems like I need to create a project(or import) for my existing directories and that seems to be OK.  Should I be doing this some other way or is there a better way to organize my files?

So far just about everything I've worked on has only a few class files and I haven't really learned about packages yet.

Comment: Why do you think that IntellJ is somehow different from other IDE's (like Eclipse or Netbeans) in this sense?

Comment: You should read about java packages structure

Comment: @om-nom-nom - I haven't used any IDE enough to know about the differences or similarities to Intellij.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I would recommend just creating a project with any name

[image]

Dragging a folder with code to project (you can also use CTRL-C and CTRL-V)
[image]

Now you have your folder in project. You can remove folder from idea without deleting files from your hard drive. You can also add multiple folders.

[image]

Profit!

Comment: I started to use packages and that kind of helps.  But I'm finding that

Comment: I'm not sure if I should ask a new question or continue this one, so adding on here.  
I started to use packages and that helps.  I realized that every time I compile/run a class somewhere in my "project" every class up the tree in other packages have to be error free or I get error messages.  How can I treat each chapter from my example above as a separate unit?  Is that possible?  I see there are excludes but that would mean excluding everything but the directory/package I'm working in and I don't want to set that for every package.   An include would work but don't see that option.

Answer (score 0):

Believe that you want to create a new module for each new homework assignment or new project.

You might create a project that's called Chapter 3 Homework and then create a new module for each new homework assignment that would have its own name, like Ch. 3.4 which would be after 3, question 4. You could also create new modules for each subject in each chapter like one for inheritance and one for Constructors or whatever.

That way, source code in 1 module would not affect another. At least I think.

Comment: Since last semester was my introduction to programing, I started out using he professors preferred editor, WordPad, which is a very basic editor and compiler. After a few weeks I started experimenting with more mature IDE's, and finally settled on Intellij (b/c it rules!). However, I didn't consider organizing my files, and was more concerned with completing my HW assignments than organization, things became messy.  I had files on different USB drives, my laptop and PC!

I think the way I'll do it now is create one project per chapter, and create modules for each assignment per chapter